# PDO binding performance tanks at certain amount of subselects

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo, prepared-statement

We switched from MariaDB to Mysql 8.0.30 last week and noticed a query that used to take around 300ms now runs for 32 seconds.
Debugging has shown that it has to do with the amount of bindings in the prepared statement and that it only shows up since MySQL version 8.0.22, before that on version 8.0.21 the problem did not exist. Changelog says that they changed the way prepared statements are executed, but I can't relate it to what's happening.

If I remove *any* of the 4 main exists() sub selects, the query executes in around 300ms again. It does not matter which one.

Inserting the values myself and executing the query directly on the query console results in the same ~300ms execution time.

Setting PDO's ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to true resolves the issue, but iirc it is discouraged for security reasons.

This also seems to at least temporarily solve the issue but performance  is worse than 300ms

```
mysqlcheck -uroot -p -o --all-databases
```

For context: These are shopping products that were automatically generated iterating through 4 different attributes and their values ("generator_conditions").
This is the query generated by Laravel 9 on PHP 8.1.1 to find products that match certain generator_condition_values:

```sql
select *
from `products`
where exists(select *
             from `products` as `laravel_reserved_0`
             where `laravel_reserved_0`.`id` = `products`.`parent_id` and `uuid` = ? and
                 exists(select *
                        from `categories`
                                 inner join `categories_product` on `categories`.`id` = `category_product`.`category_id`
                        where `laravel_reserved_0`.`id` = `category_product`.`product_id` and `uuid` = ?) and `laravel_reserved_0`.`deleted_at` is null) and
    exists(select *
           from `generator_condition_values`
                    inner join `generator_condition_value_product` on `generator_condition_values`.`id` = `generator_condition_value_product`.`generator_condition_value_id`
           where `products`.`id` = `generator_condition_value_product`.`product_id` and
               exists(select * from `generator_conditions` where `generator_condition_values`.`generator_condition_id` = `generator_conditions`.`id` and `name` = ?) and `min_value` <= ? and
               (`max_value` >= ? or `max_value` is null)) and
    exists(select *
           from `generator_condition_values`
                    inner join `generator_condition_value_product` on `generator_condition_values`.`id` = `generator_condition_value_product`.`generator_condition_value_id`
           where `products`.`id` = `generator_condition_value_product`.`product_id` and
               exists(select * from `generator_conditions` where `generator_condition_values`.`generator_condition_id` = `generator_conditions`.`id` and `name` = ?) and `min_value` <= ? and
               (`max_value` >= ? or `max_value` is null)) and
    exists(select *
           from `generator_condition_values`
                    inner join `generator_condition_value_product` on `generator_condition_values`.`id` = `generator_condition_value_product`.`generator_condition_value_id`
           where `products`.`id` = `generator_condition_value_product`.`product_id` and
               exists(select * from `generator_conditions` where `generator_condition_values`.`generator_condition_id` = `generator_conditions`.`id` and `name` = ?) and `single_value` = ?) and
    exists(select *
           from `generator_condition_values`
                    inner join `generator_condition_value_product` on `generator_condition_values`.`id` = `generator_condition_value_product`.`generator_condition_value_id`
           where `products`.`id` = `generator_condition_value_product`.`product_id` and
               exists(select * from `generator_conditions` where `generator_condition_values`.`generator_condition_id` = `generator_conditions`.`id` and `name` = ?) and `single_value` = ?)
```

Bindings:

```php
$bindings = [
    'f607e02a-4003-4852-a72c-42632a5d53a4',
    '5b863422-7b7f-4d34-9077-c2712555fa4d',
    'device_price',
    '1700',
    '1700',
    'device_age',
    0,
    0,
    'is_refurbished',
    '0',
    'is_commercial',
    '0',
];
```

Explain result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "laravel_reserved_0",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,products_uuid_index",
        "key": "products_uuid_index",
        "key_len": "144",
        "ref": "const",
        "rows": 1,
        "filtered": 10,
        "Extra": "Using where; Start temporary"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "categories",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,categories_uuid_index",
        "key": "categories_uuid_index",
        "key_len": "144",
        "ref": "const",
        "rows": 1,
        "filtered": 100,
        "Extra": "Using index"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "category_product",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,category_product_category_id_index,category_product_product_id_index",
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "key_len": "16",
        "ref": "shop.categories.id,shop.laravel_reserved_0.id",
        "rows": 1,
        "filtered": 100,
        "Extra": "Using index"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "generator_conditions",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "ALL",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
        "key": null,
        "key_len": null,
        "ref": null,
        "rows": 4,
        "filtered": 25,
        "Extra": "Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "products",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,products_parent_id_foreign",
        "key": "products_parent_id_foreign",
        "key_len": "9",
        "ref": "shop.laravel_reserved_0.id",
        "rows": 4,
        "filtered": 100,
        "Extra": null
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "generator_condition_value_product",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,gcv_id_primary,p_id_primary",
        "key": "p_id_primary",
        "key_len": "8",
        "ref": "shop.products.id",
        "rows": 4,
        "filtered": 100,
        "Extra": "Using index"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "generator_condition_values",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,condition_value_unique",
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "key_len": "8",
        "ref": "shop.generator_condition_value_product.generator_condition_value_id",
        "rows": 1,
        "filtered": 10,
        "Extra": "Using where"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "generator_condition_value_product",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,gcv_id_primary,p_id_primary",
        "key": "p_id_primary",
        "key_len": "8",
        "ref": "shop.products.id",
        "rows": 4,
        "filtered": 100,
        "Extra": "Using index"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "generator_conditions",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "key_len": "8",
        "ref": "shop.generator_condition_values.generator_condition_id",
        "rows": 1,
        "filtered": 25,
        "Extra": "Using where"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "generator_condition_values",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,condition_value_unique",
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "key_len": "8",
        "ref": "shop.generator_condition_value_product.generator_condition_value_id",
        "rows": 1,
        "filtered": 10,
        "Extra": "Using where"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "generator_conditions",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "key_len": "8",
        "ref": "shop.generator_condition_values.generator_condition_id",
        "rows": 1,
        "filtered": 25,
        "Extra": "Using where"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "generator_condition_value_product",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,gcv_id_primary,p_id_primary",
        "key": "p_id_primary",
        "key_len": "8",
        "ref": "shop.products.id",
        "rows": 4,
        "filtered": 100,
        "Extra": "Using index"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "generator_condition_values",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,condition_value_unique",
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "key_len": "8",
        "ref": "shop.generator_condition_value_product.generator_condition_value_id",
        "rows": 1,
        "filtered": 13.33,
        "Extra": "Using where"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "generator_condition_value_product",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,gcv_id_primary,p_id_primary",
        "key": "p_id_primary",
        "key_len": "8",
        "ref": "shop.products.id",
        "rows": 4,
        "filtered": 100,
        "Extra": "Using index"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "generator_conditions",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY",
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "key_len": "8",
        "ref": "shop.generator_condition_values.generator_condition_id",
        "rows": 1,
        "filtered": 25,
        "Extra": "Using where"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "select_type": "SIMPLE",
        "table": "generator_condition_values",
        "partitions": null,
        "type": "eq_ref",
        "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,condition_value_unique",
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "key_len": "8",
        "ref": "shop.generator_condition_value_product.generator_condition_value_id",
        "rows": 1,
        "filtered": 5,
        "Extra": "Using where; End temporary"
    }
]
```

Any idea why just a few more bindings completely ruin performance?
If the actual table structure is needed for context please let me know and I'll add it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I would like to know various things, starting with what `p_id_PRIMARY` is.  And:  How much RAM do you have.  And what is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.  And how big is the table.  (UUIDs are terrible for the performance of huge tables; I want to see if _this_ is reaching into that realm.

Answer (score 0):

The number of bindings has little, if any, impact on the speed of the query.  What matters is the complexity.  You can demonstrate this by filling in reasonable values and timing the bound query.

That query is quite complex.  FOr each row in `products`, it does a lookup in 5 other tables.  Each  of those lookups does another lookup in another table.

Try to rewrite the whole query as the `JOIN` (or probably `LEFT JOIN`) of several (6? 11?) tables.

Also, consider adding these indexes

```
category_product:  INDEX(uuid, product_id, category_id)
products:  INDEX(uuid, parent_id)
generator_condition_values:  INDEX(generator_condition_id)
generator_condition_value_product:  INDEX(product_id, generator_condition_value_id)
generator_conditions:  INDEX(name)
```

Some of my index suggestions may not work -- since I cannot tell what tables `uuid` and `name` are in.

```
(`max_value` >= ?  or  `max_value` is null)
```

-- ORs are hard to optimize; see if you can get rid of the test for NULL.

For further discussion, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: It's a heavy query for sure, but 300ms was always acceptable. The weird thing is that just by removing one of the exists() on generator_condition_values, everything is completely fine. Adding that one extra pushes it up to 32 seconds, which is not really explainable by just a simple hit by another exists().
Indexes you mentioned are all set except the one on the condition name.

Comment: @RemizZ - Tell me which clause(s) cause that dramatic slowdown.  I may be able to spot somethings.   Let's see the `EXPLAIN` to verify that it is actually using those indexes (or shunning them for some reason).

Comment: Since my colleague's comment was deleted I've added the explain result in the original post. As to your question: It's not one specific clause that slows it down. You can remove any of the 4 exists() subqueries and everything is fine. That's the weird part.

Comment: Yes, quite weird.  Try to rewrite the query, in hopes of making the problem go away.  Maybe you can combine the 4 uses of `generator_condition_values` into a single subselect?  Also, note that 8.0 has CTEs (`WITH`).

Comment: Since it's auto-generated by Laravel/Eloquent/Query Builder there's not much I can do if I don't want to resort to raw queries. This might be a bug in PDO or MySQL itself, I'll try taking it up to them. Thank you for your time.