# MYSQL query performance very poor when using PHP mysqli_stmt::bind_param() compared to PDOStatement::bindParam()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I am having a performance issue related to using PHP `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()` when running the following:

```
$sql = "select ts from scans where sessionid = ? order by id desc limit 1";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param("i", $row_sid );

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array(); 

$stmt->close();
```

This query is taking 2 seconds for the worse case where `scans` table have over 20000 points with the respective `row_sid = 10`, but this only happens when using `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`.

If I run the query by itself as:

```
select ts from scans where sessionid = 10 order by id desc limit 1;
```

It returns in 0.016 seconds.

The same if I do not use bind parameter:

```
$sql = "select ts from scans where sessionid = 10 order by id desc limit 1";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array(); 

$stmt->close();
```

This also returns in milliseconds.

Follow the scans table details:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE

scans | CREATE TABLE `scans` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `devid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `sessionid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `ts` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `irpwr` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `ir_v` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `ir_i` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `scans_sessionid` (`sessionid`),
  KEY `scans_devlid` (`devid`,`lid`),
  KEY `scans_ts` (`ts`),
  KEY `scans_lid` (`lid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43769072 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Edit:

I did a test using **PDO** instead of **mysqli** and the performance improved drastically, both using `bindValue()` and `bindParam()` it returned close to the direct query speed. Although, I did not find any information showing the reason for the performance difference as mysqli has proven to be faster in Benchmarks.

I may have run into a bug that I don't understand.

Comment: `Even though I fixed the sessionid as 10 which is the biggest query`...probably because it's just executing the same query 40 times, so it only has to run it once, and then return you some cached data every time thereafter.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table?

Comment: `It returns in milliseconds.` -- how *many* milliseconds? If you're executing the query 40 times and that takes 2 seconds, then the `bind_param` solution is averaging 50 ms per query.

Comment: It might be more efficient to execute a single query (`where sessionid in (<your 40 ids>)`).

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The query needs an index _starting with_ `sessionid`.

Comment: To be more specific. If I run the query, one time, without any parameter binding, it takes 0.016s while the same query, a single time. using bind_param takes 2 seconds. I edited the text to include the create table statement.

Comment: @rickdenhaan - `IN(<40 ids>)` is a _different_ query; it will not be optimized the same way and is very likely to be much slower simply due to having more than one `id`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72989927/mysql-slow-execution-of-in-query-with-prepare-statement-after-upgrading-from-5-7 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73210332/poor-performance-on-specific-queries-after-mysql-8-0-upgrade

Comment: The difference between PDO and mysqli is easily explainable, PDO by default doesn't use them. There is indeed something with the way mysql executes prepared statements

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73473819/pdo-binding-performance-tanks-at-certain-amount-of-subselects

Comment: Another clue may come from the following:  Turn on the "general log".  Run both variations (PDO/bind) of the query.  Turn off the general log.  Find both exact queries in the general log.  Show them to us for comparision.

Answer (score -1):

To "prove" that the "bind" is at fault, pepper the PHP code with `microtime(true)` to separate out the call to bind.

To time any SQL query, run it twice.  There are multiple caches that interfere with getting a realistic time.

- If the data is not yet cached in the buffer_pool (or other RAM caches), the first run will be slow because of the I/O; the second will be a realistic estimate for production use of the query.
- If the "Query cache" is ON, the *second* time will be on the order of 1 millisecond, regardless of how complex the query is.  The QC is going away; plan for its future removal.  Meanwhile, do `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` then timing.

Back to the specific query...

```
select  ts
    from  scans
    where  sessionid = ?
    order by  id desc
    limit  1
```

will run faster with

```
INDEX(session_id, id, ts)
```

When Adding that, also Drop the existing INDEX(session_id) as being redundant.